# combobox qml in QT stay down

Tags: qt, combobox, qml

I add simple combobox in my qml form but after selection, the button of it stay blue like the mouse stay clicked and I can not select any more after the first click, do you know why?...

```
ComboBox{
model:["test1","test2"]
}
```

image upload is not working then here drive link to see what I mean:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Un0pOCTbmEu_FeCHDzTYKF8FbV4YTxHR

[image]

thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: mcve? what do you mean?... I provided the code and picture, what do you want more than that? I don't have any error message concerning this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt 5.10.0 added support for native menus on Windows. This caused a regression in Qt Quick Controls 1 ComboBox. ComboBox did not get notified that the menu popup was closed, so it thought it was still pressed and therefore refused to re-open the popup. The bug ([QTBUG-64628](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64628)) has been fixed in Qt 5.10.1. Try updating.

Comment: oh oki, thank you, I will update it and give feedback after ;-)